# Understanding て in 言葉{ことば}を失{な}くして 壁{かべ}は無関心{むかんしん}

Tags: song-lyrics, て-form

This is from a song lyrics (転{ころ}がる石{いし}になれ by AKB48)

孤独{こどく}は　いつでも
自由{じゆう}の代償{だいしょう}に
言葉{ことば}を失{な}くして
壁{かべ}は無関心{むかんしん}
耐{た}えるしかないよ

Does て here indicate a command, as in "lose the talk"?

Or, is it connected to the next phrase? Perhaps as a description of 壁{かべ}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to try to parse the stanza:

- 孤独{こどく}は - loneliness (establish context)
- いつでも - any time
- 自由{じゆう}の代償{だいしょう}に - price of freedom (dative/locative case?)
- (A pause in the singing)
- 言葉{ことば}を失{な}くして - to get rid of (the) word(s) (requesting)
- 壁{かべ}は- wall/barrier (establish context)
- 無{む}関{かん}心{しん} - indifferent
- 耐{た}えるしかないよ - no choice but to endure

---

There seems to be a lot of elision going on. I'm going to try to put it back together.

- 孤独はいつでも自由の代償にある - loneliness is always in the price of (our) freedom
- 言葉を失くしてください - please get rid of words*

*<sub>(I'm guessing this in the sense of "actions speak louder than words" kind of meaning)</sub>

- 壁は無関心です - the barrier is indifferent (to attempts at overcoming it)
- 耐えるしかないよ - (we) have no choice but to endure

Comment: Thanks! I like your interpretation of "indifferent" (to attempts at overcoming it). Your interpretation of 言葉を失くして also makes a lot of sense.

Comment: For consideration: 言葉を[失]{うしな}う means "be at a loss for words". I'm not sure if 言葉を[失]{な}くす has a similar meaning. If so then that part would probably mean "Because we're at a loss for words, the barrier is indifferent" (て-form of the verb implying temporal order or weak causal relation).